# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text' python 3x

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been strugeling with this code:

```
def MainPageSpider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = 'url' + str(page)
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = bs(plain_text, 'html.parser')
        for link in soup.findAll(attrs={'class':'col4'}):
            href = 'url' + link.a['href']
            title = link.span.text

            PostPageItems(href)
        page += 1


def PostPageItems(post_url):
    source_code = requests.get(post_url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = bs(plain_text, 'html.parser')
    for items in soup.findAll(attrs={'class':'container'}):
        title2 = items.find('h1', {'class':'title'}).get_text()

        print(title2)




MainPageSpider(1)
```

Every time I try to get the text from 'h1' I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Xfeed.py", line 33, in <module>
    MainPageSpider(1)
  File "Xfeed.py", line 17, in MainPageSpider
    PostPageItems(href)
  File "Xfeed.py", line 27, in PostPageItems
    test = title2.get_text()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

But when I run it without 'get_text()' I will get the 'h1' HTML:

```
<h1 class="title">Title 1</h1>
None
None
None
None
<h1 class="title">Title 2</h1>
None
None
None
None
<h1 class="title">Title 3</h1>
None
None
None
None
```

I don't really understand why this error while with `title = link.span.text` I don't have any problem getting the text.
I only want the text.

Comment: if items doesn't have a `h1` entry then `find` will return `None`, which is why you're seeing all the `None`s between each `h1` in your output.  You need to handle that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not every `container` has an `h1`, so just check if `None` is returned and then print only if not.

```
for items in soup.findAll(attrs={'class':'container'}):
        title2 = items.find('h1', {'class':'title'})
        if title2:
            print(title2.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the output without `get_text()` it looks like title2 is often `None` which should fail with the error you posted since `None` does not have the `get_text()` attribute. You could split this into 2 statements and add a check as below:

```py
title2_item = items.find('h1', {'class':'title'})

if title2_item: # Check for None
    title2 = title2_item.get_text()
    print(title2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Re-write using a css selector that only selects for qualifying elements

```
for item in soup.select('.container h1.title'):
        title2 = item.text
```